# I have a List<> and INT and I want to use the INT to point which index in the List<> should be updating now but couldn't make it work good

Tags: c#

In the top Form1 level I have:

```
List<float> cyclicSelectedIndex = new List<float>(2);
int currentCyclicIndex;
```

In the constructor I have:

```
currentCyclicIndex = 0;
```

And this is the mouse down event where I have the selectedIndex when clicking on a point:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
        label1.Text = e.X.ToString();
        label2.Text = e.Y.ToString();
        label1.Visible = true;
        label2.Visible = true;
        label3.Visible = true;
        label4.Visible = true;
        // find the index that is closest to the current mouse location
        MinDist = float.MaxValue;

        for (idx = 0; idx < Point_X.Count; ++idx) {
            float dx = Point_X[idx] - e.X;
            float dy = Point_Y[idx] - e.Y;
            float dist = (float)Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

            if (dist < MinDist) {
                MinDist = dist;
                selectedIndex = idx;
            }
        }

        if (MinDist < 5) {
            mouseMove = true;
            OriginalX = Point_X[(int)selectedIndex];
            OriginalY = Point_Y[(int)selectedIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

I want in the mouse down event in cyclic way logic to add the selectedIndex to the List according the INT variable pointing.

Once the int is 0 and once its 1. And each time it will contain or point at another selectedIndex number which meaning I clicked on two different points.

So if I click on one point it will add the point selectedIndex to the cyclic List at index 0 using the INT variable.

And then if I click on any other point it will add the other point selectedIndex to to index 1 in the cyclic List using the INT variable.

The idea is to make a cyclic List so when I click a two points it will not delete the last index but will puse the last one so once I click a point it will add the selectedIndex to index 0 clicked on another point it will add the selectedIndex to index 0 and move the other index to 1 and so on. Cyclic.

I need to make something in the mouse down event to add some code and make that when I click on a point like now and the I have the selectedIndex so if I click after it on another point I will have a new variable with the other clicked point index for example: selectedIndex1

And then I want in the mouse down event to use the int variable to add to the List<> each time the last selectedIndex or selectedIndex1 to the place in the List using the int.

Comment: I dont know how ot find/get the second selectedIndex1. Now i know how to get the selectedIndex when i click on a point but when i click after it on another point the selectedIndex is different but how do i put the second point selectedIndex in another variable so selectedIndex will hold the index of the first clicked point and selectedIndex1 will hold the index of the second clicked point. The indexs and points location are hold in the Point_X List<> and Point_Y List<>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list is empty after creation, even if you specify a size in the constructor. This space is only the initially reserved space for the later addition of items. You have to add items with `Add`.

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(10);
list.Add(7);
```

If you have a fixed size, use an array instead

```
int[] cyclicArray = new int[2];
int index = 0;
```

Increment the index like this, using a modulo operation

```
index = (index + 1) % 2;
```

The index will cycle like this: 0, 1, 0, 1, ...

```
cyclicArray[index] = someValue;
```

---

UPDATE

You can use the `PointF` structure to store x/y-coordinates as `float` values.

```
List<PointF> cyclicPoints = new List<PointF>(2);
int currentCyclicIndex;
```

After having found a OriginalX/Y, add a element to the list if its size is smaller than 2, or change a existing element at a cyclic position otherwise.

```
PointF point = new PointF(OriginalX, OriginalY);
if (cyclicPoints.Count < 2) {
    cyclicPoints.Add(point);
} else {
    cyclicPoints[currentCyclicIndex] = point;
    currentCyclicIndex = (currentCyclicIndex + 1) % 2;
}
```

You can access a point coordinate in the list like this:

```
float x = cyclicPoints[0].X;
float y = cyclicPoints[0].Y;
```

---

UPDATE #2

If you want to store the index, define your list as list of `int`, not of `float` or `PointF`

```
List<int> cyclicSelectedIndex = new List<int>(2); 
if (cyclicSelectedIndex.Count < 2) {
    cyclicSelectedIndex.Add((int)selectedIndex);
} else {
    cyclicSelectedIndex[currentCyclicIndex] = (int)selectedIndex;
    currentCyclicIndex = (currentCyclicIndex + 1) % 2;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry for not referring to your code example, but I am bit confused on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes hard to explain. I have two lists: Point_X and Point_Y each List containing number of indexs each index contain a point location. In the X list the location of each point of the X coordinate and same for the Y list. Now in the mouse down event i did that when i click on a button any button it will calculate the nearest button i cliked on from the other button and also check if its distance lower then 5 pixels from the point center. So this point selected and i get the point selectedIndex.

Comment: In the selectedIndex variable i have the index from the Point_X list of the last point i clicked on. Now i want to make that if i click on another point the second point index will be in a new variable like selectedIndex1 . So in the end selectedIndex will hold the index of the first point i clicked and selectedIndex1 will hold the second point index i clicked and if i will click again on third point the index in selectedIndex will change for the index of the third point i clicked. and so on. All the time when i click on point and another point ill have them indexs in two different variables.

Comment: Olivier i did this                 PointF point = new PointF(OriginalX, OriginalY);
                if (cyclicSelectedIndex.Count < 2)
                {
                    cyclicSelectedIndex.Add(point);
                }
                else
                {
                    cyclicSelectedIndex[currentCyclicIndex] = point;
                    currentCyclicIndex = (currentCyclicIndex + 1) % 2;
                } but i have two problems : cyclicSelectedIndex List is type of float and cant add PointF

Comment: the second problem is: cyclicSelectedIndex[currentCyclicIndex] = point; cant convert pointf                              In both problems its with the list and pointf

Comment: Ok Olivier it seems to be working now. I will test it some more but it seems to be working now. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of having two `List<float>` for `Point_X` and `Point_Y` you could have a single `List<PointF>` for them as well; or a `List<Point>` if you need integer coordinates.

Comment: Olivier could you show me please how to do it but using a List of type INT ? Not PointF. Thank you.

Comment: I did a mistake sorry. I dont need in the cyclic List the cyclicSelectedIndex to hold there X and Y. I need to hold there in index 0 the variable selectedIndex wich contain the index of the point i just clicked. And when i click on another point the selectedIndex is updated to the other point index and this index should be in the List<int> cyclicSelectedIndex at index number 1. So each time i click a point it will store its index ( not coordinates ) just the index once in 0 once in 1 using the currentCyclicIndex int variable.

Comment: This is easy to figure out now. See my UPDATE #2.